# Расчет количества разных слов в тексте

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Необходимо подсчитать количество уникальных слов в тексте. Как сделать цикл чтобы подчитать количество? Вот что у меня есть.

```
    int main()
{
   SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char str[N];
    printf("Введите текст");
    gets_s(str); 
}
```

Comment: Ответ желательно должен быть на си

Comment: Тогда не надо было ставить тег C++. :/

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

- `unordered_set` будет хранить только уникальные значения слов и его размер будет равен количеству уникальных слов.
- `ss >> s` будет клась в s очередное слово, написанное через пробел после предыдущего.

```
char str[N];
printf("Введите текст");
gets_s(str); 
std::unordered_set<std::string> st;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << str;
std::string s;
while (ss >> s) {
    st.insert(s)
}
std::cout << st.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: А можете переписать под си?